# Movie with an alien with purple eyes that possesses a child

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm trying to remember a movie about aliens, where a guy comes across a purple wall and later gets possessed by aliens?

When possessed he tries to kill his wife, he looks the same, though he has (at times) **purple eyes** and that's the only way one can recognise he's possessed

I also remember that last scene included a shot of his newborn baby, and while everything appears to be happily ever after, the baby has purple eyes like being possessed by an alien.

What was that movie?